# change popup height

Tags: swing, height, popupmenu

I have a Java swing popupmenu with a couple of menuItems.

Is there any way to increase the size of the popup keeping the same number of menuItems? For example, add 10px before the 1st menuItem and 10px after the last menuItem.

How can I do this? Can someone give me an hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Since `JPopupMenu` is a `Container` the following code will produce the effect you desire

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100,10));
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100,10));

menu.add(p1);
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 1"));
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 3"));    
menu.add(p2);
```